# mvc3 is there a way to change the naming system of razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a partial view that allows Html and the rendered `name` attribute of the `<textarea>` is throwing everything off, for instance this is my text area

```
     @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.cars.mycars)
```

causes the attribute to render as `name="cars.mycars"`, is there anyway to change that to **cars_mycars** without using **@Name** ?

The reason why I want **cars_mycars** is because it is a field that has AllowHtml in it in the model

```
   [AllowHtml]
     public string mycars { get; set; }
```

In order for AllowHtml to work I would need a strongly typed model such as **@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.mycars)** but I am using multiple models in 1 view therefore I have

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.cars.mycars, @new{id="cars_mycars",@Name="cars_mycars"})
```

This is all in a partialview and when I try to submit it nothing happens at all. That is the only field in the form so the issue much lie there and in addition if I put

```
ValidateInput(False)
```

on the action method then everything works fine which leads me back to the @name convention not working .

Comment: I've edited your question to make it clearer, did I understand your question correctly? Also, why do you want "`cars_mycars`" as name value? (Because ASP.NET MVC uses its own format for model binding).

Comment: I wanted that as a name value because my form is inside a partial and I think thats how it communicates in partials. I have AllowHtml working on a different controller and it works fine the only difference with this one is the cars.mycars

Comment: Are you trying to post master detail view ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
@Html.TextArea("cars_mycars")
```